# Is there any way to change LAN MAC address on Wi-Fi router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, lan, mac-address

I have a Wi-Fi router which has WLAN MAC address and LAN MAC address. I can spoof WLAN MAC address easily, but can not spoof in the same way on LAN MAC address. How can I spoof the LAN MAC address?

Comment: What is the model of your WiFi router?

Comment: What do the instructions for the router say? Have you looked anything up yourself?

Comment: On most routers you can't. Why would you want this?

Comment: @Steven It's TENDA W268R

Comment: @JulianKnight it's actually my friend's router, and he's not even knows about it.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, it's not any harm purpose,   i'm just a geek :)

Comment: Not really a good idea to mess around with MAC addresses unless you have to, especially on consumer routers that, even if they allow you to change this, are probably not well tested for "odd" configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Scan through each page of the router configuration to find a LAN-side MAC address setting.

However, it is unlikely the router will have this setting.

Answer (score 0):

If its not in the menu...
look for settings in and export, maybe you can edit a mac cloning parameter in the resulting configfile.
But most home routers allow only to spoof wan mac adress for identification by your isp.

Seems like no custom OS support like openwrt.
If you find a way to get console access, you may find some kind of linux, where you can dig further into settings.